# session.SaveChanges() not working

Tags: asp.net, ravendb, updating

I'm officially perplexed. I have a Quote object that already exists in the DB, and I'm trying to update it. It never seems to save to the DB after I make my changes and call SaveChanges()

```
   quote = session.Load<Quote>(QuoteID);
        if (quote == null)
        {
            quote = new Quote();
            session.Store(quote);
        }
        else
        {
            temp.Id = quote.Id;
            temp.Lines = quote.Lines;
        }

        quote = temp;
        //breakpoint here, quote has the correct ID and updated info
        session.SaveChanges();
```

I refresh the page and it Loads the same quote in Page_Load() and it sets my textboxes back to the old stale data.

```
   List<Quote> DBquotes = session.Query<Quote>().ToList();
        if (DBquotes.Count() == 0) quote = new Quote();
        else
        {
            //TODO: ability to choose/load quote
            QuoteID = DBquotes[0].Id;
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadQuote(QuoteID);
            repHW.DataSource = quote.Lines; 
            repHW.DataBind();
        }
```

Here's the actual load line in LoadQuote()

```
    protected void LoadQuote(string ID)
    {
        quote = session.Load<Quote>(QuoteID);
        ...
    }
```

What am I missing? Why does it not want to save my data? :/

Comment: Looks like `session.Save()` is never called unless quote is null.  Shouldn't it also be called when quote is not null?

Comment: what happens when you call `SaveChanges()` directly after storing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning the quote object to temp will not allow you to use `session.SaveChanges()` without doing another `session.Store(quote);` 
So either make the changes on the quote object itself or call `session.Store(quote);` again.

**More Detail:**
When you load an object from Raven it is actually a proxy class with tracking enabled. If you make changes to this object then you will not have to do anything else other than call `session.SaveChanges()` However, when you do this
`quote = temp;` you lose the reference to that object and have replaced it with your own object that has no tracking enabled on it.

Comment: this solved my issue, thank you! learned something new today.